# Django admin panel checkbox have label to the left

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django checkbox in the admin panel. However it looks bad and doesn't conform to the other properties with a label on the left and then the option on the right. Is it possible to change it?

[default checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFlem.png)

```
class myForm(models.Model):
    required = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```